# Symfony 4 - some difficults with make a Doctrine findBy with parameters

Tags: function, symfony, doctrine

I took over an old project under Symfony 4, which I would like to improve.

I have pages that use pagination, with a service that I created that takes parameters like class, maximum number of elements per page, and so on.

On one of my pages, I added a search field to filter by name the display of a list.

To give you an idea of the function that returns the data:

```
   /**
     * Permet de récupérer les données paginées pour une entité spécifique
     * 
     * Elle se sert de Doctrine afin de récupérer le repository pour l'entité spécifiée
     * puis grâce au repository et à sa fonction findBy() on récupère les données dans une 
     * certaine limite et en partant d'un offset
     * 
     * @throws Exception si la propriété $entityClass n'est pas définie
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (empty($this->entityClass)) {
            throw new \Exception("Vous n'avez pas spécifié l'entité sur laquelle nous devons paginer ! Utilisez la méthode setEntityClass() de votre objet PaginationService !");
        }
        // 1) Calculer l'offset
        $offset = $this->currentPage * $this->limit - $this->limit;
        // 2) Demander au repository de trouver les éléments à partir d'un offset et 
        // dans la limite d'éléments imposée (voir propriété $limit)
        return $this->manager
            ->getRepository($this->entityClass)
            ->findBy([], [], $this->limit, $offset);
    }
```

So now my goal is to ensure that the function can handle the case when I asked him to sort in the results due to a request DQL example.

On one of my pages, thanks to the search filter, I have to enter the first name or the name of a user (or some characters are enough).

This translates to the following DQL query:

```
public function getUsersByName($name)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.nom LIKE :name OR u.prenom LIKE :name')
            ->setParameter('name', $name . '%')
            ->orderBy('u.nom', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```

How could I integrate this into my function? The goal being to do that for any query eventually. I just need to add the limit and the offset to the result

EDIT:

Is is possible to make something like :

```
$function = getUsersByName;
$parameters = $this->name;

return $this->manager
            ->getRepository($this->entityClass)
            ->$function($parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, you just need to replace :

```
return $this->manager
            ->getRepository($this->entityClass)
            ->findBy([], [], $this->limit, $offset);
```

by :

```
return $this->manager
            ->getRepository($this->entityClass)
            ->getUsersByName($name, $this->limit, $offset);
```

Assuming you changed the method in your Repo for :

```
public function getUsersByName($name, $limit = null, $offset = 0)
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.nom LIKE :name OR u.prenom LIKE :name')
            ->setParameter('name', $name . '%')
            ->orderBy('u.nom', 'ASC');
        if($limit){
            $query->setFirstResult($offset)
                  ->setMaxResults($limit);
        }

        return $query->getQuery()
              ->getResult();
    }
```

Did I understand your problem well ?

Comment: I forgot the return :)

Comment: Yes, it's better ! But can I make something like ( view my edit first post)

Comment: If you are 100% sure of the parameters you giv to your function, yeah, you can do something like this! (maybe you will have to add brackets like this :   return $this->manager->getRepository($this->entityClass)->{$function}($parameters); )